# Android (2.1) HttpGet.abort() is not working

Tags: android, http-get, abort

I call abort() and the thread that is blocking in execute() doesn't unblock until it times out with an exception.  It can take over 10 seconds, so this is a big problem.

I've looked around for a while and I can't find the answer to this.

The docs say that abort() should cause the execute() blocking i/o to unblock immediately.  Research suggests that this problem was fixed a while ago.

I am calling abort() and execute() from different threads, of course.  There's nothing special about my code, so I won't waste space listing it.

Some posts I found suggested messing with the sockets and such underneath the HttpClient, but none of those worked either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting HttpGet to timeout after a known amount of time, or is there a reason why you must try to cancel the get? I suspect that abort only works after it has a response stream to be reading...as in abort a long download. You might try using URLConnection instead of HttpGet which allows you to set read and connection timeouts independently.

```
URL url= new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(getInstance().getConnectionTimeout());
        conn.setReadTimeout(getInstance().getReadTimeout());
        if (encodedPostargs != null)
        {
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            out.write(encodedPostargs);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't need a timeout, I want to allow the user to cancel an http request if they so desire. I think I figured out the problem: the thread isn't in an I/O call when I am aborting, it is in the TrustManager constructor. This makes sense as I am using https.  I'm going to look into it further, but this specific problem is resolved since it wasn't the actual problem.  Oopsies...

Comment: Update: Yeah, I just moved the keystore init code into a spot that happens before i do the execute().  abort() works as documented with the blocking I/O. The only problem now is the slow startup of the app due to the keystore init. I guess a splash screen or some non-cancelable progress indicator would be in order...